# app engine failed to create default storage bucket

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

In Administration -> Application Settings -> Cloud Integration it says: 
An error occurred when creating the project. Please retry.
then there is a retry button, I clicked the button, few minutes later it still shows that error.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Please anybody provide us the solution.

Comment: Same here, started trying to use it since 2014-09-26 and no luck on various (and new) projects. Interestingly, I have one project with it already created and that bucket gives a 404, wtf...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer:

appengine.google.com is the old place to create projects.

The new place is https://console.developers.google.com/project, and when creating projects in the new place, you need to create a bucket yourself, then you can use it like this(in php): file_put_contents("gs://bucket_name/object_name", "hello");

Comment: you need also to enable billing to use cloud storage, but it still has free quota