# Cloud Storage Integration failed and not able to add manually created bucket in WordPress AppEngine plugin

Tags: google-app-engine, wordpress, google-cloud-storage

AFter looking for several questions already present in here, I am putting here more specific problem about Google Cloud Storage Integration and WordPress AppEngine plugin.

I was following the steps mentioned here:[WordPress for Google App Engine](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/).
The problems:

1. For auto creation of GCS, I followed `Administration -> Application Settings -> Cloud Integration`. It says: An error occurred when creating the project. Please retry.
2. As I was unable to create the bucket using above step, so I tried to create it manually and added the same in the WordPress AppEngine plugin, but it says: Invalid bucket or bucket is not writable. Please note that I had created the bucket with the service-account id as a user with write privilege.

So in both the way It was not solving the problem.

Comment: For 1. it seems Google has problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26074690/app-engine-failed-to-create-default-storage-bucket. For 2. it should work, and if you added the permission I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie  yes you can see my comments there. But here i have explained the problem in-depth.

Comment: After reporting this issue to Google [https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11342],  it is not replicable for me. @Tjorriemorrie are you still able to replicate it?